# Замер времени выполнения в mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc

В представлении "создать" есть есть форма в которой два поля: дата и номер документа.

Они общие для всех строк, а 2 поля количество и название можно клонировать с помощью кнопки + строка (срабатывает функция клонирования), с помощью цикла в этой функции я создал 100 строк для заполнения (количество и названия).

На сервере в методе Post принимаю все значения формы с помощью Form Collection.

Здесь реализую добавление строк на сервер с помощью табличного параметра:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
   dt.Rows.Add(i, $"Name {i}");

using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
   cmd.Connection = connection;
   cmd.CommandText = @"insert into [Table] (ID, Name) select ID, Name from @data";

   var p = new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.Structured);
   p.TypeName = "dbo.TableType";
   p.Value = dt;

   cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Собственно как замерить время выполнения сего монстра?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Со стороны кода:

  ```
  Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
  watch.Start();

  // Код

  watch.Stop();
  var elapsedTime = watch.Elapsed;
  ```
- Со стороны базы данных — профайлером базы данных.
- Со стороны браузера — посмотреть время выполнения запроса в панели разработчика на вкладке сеть.

Comment: В целом — да. Добавляется только учет накладных расходов. Если вас интересует именно время выполнения запроса, то лучший вариант это воспользоваться иструментарием базы данных.

Comment: profiler ставится отдельно от sql server?

Comment: Если вас интересует скорость выполнения запроса то эту метрику показывает SSMS. Если вам нужно посмотреть, на то, какие шаги выполняет запрос и на что тратит время, то воспользуйтесь вкладкой Execution Plan

Comment: Для более серьезной трассировки запроса используйте профайлер — https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181091.aspx

Comment: Идеально было бы от нажатия кнопки submit на view до записи 100 строк в таблицу на сервере.

Comment: Для более точных измерений лучше замерить всё сегментами. Отдельно фронтенд и отдельно бекенд. Измерять сетевые коммуникации в вашем случае бесполезное занятие.

Comment: Для кода можете еще в сторону [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) копнуть